How to correctly specify an archiver (ar) in CMake via command line?
How to correctly specify an archiver in CMake via command line?
I've tried:
$ AR=xxx cmake ...
$ CMAKE_AR=xxx cmake ...

However, cmake keeps using /usr/bin/ar instead of specified ar (which is not /usr/bin/ar).

CMAKE_AR should be CMake variable, not environment one. cmake -DCMAKE_AR=xxx ...
